# How does the add comment option work on this site?

Tags: language-agnostic

I want an option like ***add comment*** in my forum to let the users post a quick reply.

Вован Путин -

Comment: Do you mean the add comment or add answer?

Comment: You have posted earlier the same question and it was closed. Please provide more info so that this also won't be closed.

Comment: I mean add comment. javascript or what? I can speak fracking english =)))

Answer (score 6):

I think you mean the 'Add Comment' option.

It's some AJAX stuff. That's how it works basically :

- Some lines of
  JavaScript calls a server-side
  page, giving it some arguments, like
  content of the comment, author, etc.
- Server do some work, here it
  certainly adds some rows in the
  database, on the comments table..
- Server give an answer to the client :
  in PHP everything that is echoed is
  returne to the client.
- Client receive    the answer, and
  manipulate the page,    usually via
  the DOM, add the HTML    that show
  the comment, refresh some    stuff,
  etc.

See [here](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/javascript/ajax.html) for tutorial and overview of this technology.

Comment: No problem, that's SO's aim to be not Google ^^

Answer (score 2):

Add comment is done using AJAX.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)

> Ajax, sometimes written as AJAX
>   (shorthand for asynchronous JavaScript
>   and XML), is a group of interrelated
>   web development techniques used on the
>   client-side to create interactive web
>   applications or rich Internet
>   applications. With Ajax, web
>   applications can retrieve data from
>   the server asynchronously in the
>   background without interfering with
>   the display and behavior of the
>   existing page. The use of Ajax has led
>   to an increase in interactive
>   animation on web pages[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)[2] and
>   better quality of Web services due to
>   the asynchronous mode. Data is usually
>   retrieved using the XMLHttpRequest
>   object. Despite the name, the use of
>   JavaScript and XML is not actually
>   required, nor do the requests need to
>   be asynchronous.[3]

Answer (score 1):

It works via HTTP.

Comment: You want to be careful making jokes at the expense of someone called "Putin"

Comment: The answer is correct, adresses the question and is not meant to be sarcastic, but merely to make the OP think about what information he actually wants and perhaps indicate so in the comments.

Comment: How does that even remotely start to address the question? That is such a vague answer that it fits with almost anything.  "How does StackOverflow.com work? It works via HTTP. How does my browser work? It works via HTTP. How does my cat get its food? It gets it via HTTP. How do post a smart-ass comment on your non-answer? I do it via HTTP." :)

Comment: It's the *question* that's extremely vague and thus near impossible to answer usefully.

Comment: So why not just either not answer or ask them to clarify in a comment?

Comment: Yes, the question is vague, but your answer is in no way helpful.